# Django duplicate database lookups with inlineformset

Tags: python, django, database, duplicates

I need help with solving an issue regarding duplicate database query's for each form in an inlineformset. I have a page where users can add and edit books belonging to an author.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_idcategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Author, id=id)
form = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, form=BookForm, can_delete=True, extra=5)
formset = form(request.POST or None, instance=instance)

if request.method == "POST":
    if formset.is_valid():
        instanceForm = formset.save(commit=False)
        for obj in instanceForm:
            obj.save()
        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(URL)
```

When I run the template, it performs a database query to the Category model for each form in formset. How do I prevent those duplicates? I dont know where to put select_related or prefetch_related. If instances of Book model grows to a large number, the page load times are getting very slow.

template.html

```
<table class="table table-sm">
{{ formset.management_form }}
    <thead>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>delete</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for obj in formset %}
    {{ obj.id }}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ obj.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.category_idcategory }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.DELETE }}</td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, can you post the template code?

Comment: added template code to the original post

Answer (score 0):

You can change the queryset of a formset like this:

```
class InlineBookFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Here is where to put the select_related.
        self.queryset = Book.objects.select_related('category_idcategory').all()
```

then in your factory method call:

```
# Use your custom InlineBookFormSet
form = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, form=BookForm, can_delete=True, extra=5, formset=InlineBookFormSet)
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work, it keeps querying the database for each form in formset